# How to prevent leading zeros after mapping to integer using python

Tags: python, list, sorting, mapping

I want to sort a list numerically

```
s = [['92', '022'],['82','12'],['77','13']]
```

so I used,

```
s = [list( map(int,i) ) for i in s]     

s.sort()
```

and output came

```
[[77, 13],[82, 12],[92, 22]]
```

But I want to keep that 22 as it is ie., "022"
so, my question is how to prevent that leading zero!

Comment: You can simply use `sorted(s)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sorted` instead with the following `key`, that way you'll avoid transforming the actual values with a list comprehension:

```
sorted(l, key = lambda x: int(x[0]))
[['77', '13'], ['82', '12'], ['92', '022']]
```

You can also use [`operators.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)as suggested by @aws_apprentice:

```
sorted(l, key = lambda x: int(itemgetter(0)(x)))
[['77', '13'], ['82', '12'], ['92', '022']]
```

Comment: I like the idea of converting to int inside the `key` argument, rather than actually changing the contents of the list. This is also possible using `sort`, e.g. `s.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[0]))`

Comment: Yes that's the idea behind @Kevin :-) Thanks

Comment: better to not use `lambda` but `itemgetter` from the `operator` module since `lambda` calls get expensive

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out, updated the answer with you suggestion @aws_apprentice

Comment: That new version, however, does not sort numerically, but lexicographically without int conversion. Also this disregards the second element entirely.

Comment: I think both your considerations are incorrect. If you do not convert to integer, it only will consider the first digit, so `110` will come before `80`, because `1<8`. And OPs expected output is only sorted using the first element in each list @schwobaseggl, so the sorting process should indeed disregard the second element

Comment: @yatu Thanks for the great answer! It works and I found both `sort` and `sorted` works and problem was that `map(int, i)` which can be easily replaced with `int(x)` inside the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the `key` function: convert the values to their sort key. So:

```
def sort_key(val):
    return list(map(int, val)) 

s.sort(key=sort_key)
# [['77', '13'], ['82', '12'], ['92', '022']]
```

should come closest to your attempted logic.